# bs4 scraping python cannot get complete href of anchor tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, scrape

I want to scrape href of anchor tag in div with class name="fixText" of this site   https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=1310738526_national-defence-university-islamabad  and cannot get complete href text. please help me.
I only get half of the href like this
"institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=721_institute-of-space-technology-islamabad"

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
from fake_useragent import  UserAgent  

ua = UserAgent()  
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}  
response = requests.get('https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=1310738526_national-defence-university-islamabad',headers=header)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')  
for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'fixText'}): 
    print(i.a['href'])
```

Comment: just add the domain name to the href like `print("https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/" + i.a['href'])`

Comment: no problem :D  .

Comment: Thanks it worked